# ObjectDisposedException / SocketsHttpHandler in .NET 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1, objectdisposedexception

I am using asp.net core in one of my projects and I am making some https requests with a client certificate. To achieve this, I created a typed http client and injected it in my startup.cs like the following:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IClientService, ClientService>(c =>
            {
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11;
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                return handler;
            }
            );
```

My service is implemented like the following:

```
 public class ClientService : IClientService
    {
        public HttpClient _httpClient { get; private set; }
        private readonly string _remoteServiceBaseUrl;
        

        private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _settings;


        public ClientService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            _settings = settings;
            _remoteServiceBaseUrl = $"{settings.Value.ClientUrl}";  /


        }

        async public Task<Model> GetInfo(string id)
        {
            var uri = ServiceAPI.API.GetOperation(_remoteServiceBaseUrl, id);
            var stream = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var cbor = CBORObject.Read(stream);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDTO>(cbor.ToJSONString());
                
        }
    }
```

In my calling class, I am using this code:

```
public class CommandsApi 
    {
        IClientService _clientService;
       
        public CommandsApi( IclientService clientService)
           : base(applicationService, loggerFactory)
        {
            _clientService = clientService;
            _loggerfactory = loggerFactory;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(V1.AddTransaction command)
        {

           
            var result = await _clientService.GetInfo(command.id);
        }
    }
```

It works just fine however after sending many requests I am receiving the foloowing error:

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SocketsHttpHandler'.
 at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.CheckDisposed()
 at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

I tried some solutions that I found in previous issues (asp.net core github )and stackoverflow but they did not work.
Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: This is a serious security bug: `handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11;` It tells .NET to *avoid* using TLS1.3 even if available and forces the use of TLS1.1 and the obsolete TLS1.0 even if they are disabled  by default. You *shouldn't* set the `SslProtocols` property and let .NET Core use the best encryption provided by the OS

Comment: Yes this is just for dev

Comment: It's not needed at all then

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's caused by resources not being disposed properly. There's an unnecessary call to **.Result** and you create a stream, but you don't dispose of it. If you use **using** statement, then the stream should be disposed. (you can always call stream.dispose() but I wouldn't recommend it).

```
var stream = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

I've not run this, but consider:

```
public async Task<Model> GetInfo(string id)
{
    var uri = ServiceAPI.API.GetOperation(_remoteServiceBaseUrl, id);
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        var cbor = CBORObject.Read(stream);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDTO>(cbor.ToJSONString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I know that the problem is caused by the HttpClientHandler but I am still trying to solve it without success

Comment: On GetInfo you have public async the wrong way around, can you double check this?

Comment: The GetInfo is just a simplified example, my API is more complex, I just gave the example on how I am calling the service.

Comment: sorry about that. I've done some digging around, as a starting point, you might want to create a class that inherits from HttpClientHandler (and contains custom code) & inject the class in. See answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875320/how-to-use-configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler-generic

Comment: My code is supposed to work correctly, I guess there is a bug in .net core.

Comment: I think you're right theres something odd in core. My guess is ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler is not disposing HttpClientHandler properly.

Answer (score 3):

So after many tests I followed @Greg advice and implemented a class inheriting from HttpClientHandler and injected it like the following:

```
services.AddTransient<MyHttpClientHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<IClientService, ClientService>().
                ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler<MyHttpClientHandler>();
```

this solved my problem.
Thank you @Greg for the link
[How to use ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875320/how-to-use-configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler-generic)

Answer (score 2):

**This is not what the original question was for**, but I stumbled onto this question while searching for a similar issue.

When adding an `HttpMessageHandler` to the `HttpClient`, make sure to always return a new `HttpMessageHandler` instance and not re-use the same  `HttpMessageHandler` instance.

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient<IClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        // Always return a new instance!!
        return new HttpClientHandler();
    });
```

The [document of the `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) states that

> The `configureHandler` delegate should return a new instance of the message handler each time it is invoked.

See this github answer for more information
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27610#issuecomment-433101757